# How to change title of a page when headers are already sent through PHP

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver

I have a couple of PHP pages which begins with a secure session start. When I put a page title in the head section it says "headers already passed". How can I put page titles while securely starting a PHP function at the beginning of the page?

Comment: Please post your code if possible.

Comment: Put your title tag after the php code

Comment: You need tp look at the line the error message is complaining about. Starting a session and then outputting the HTML should never be a problem.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/2493019

Answer (score 1):

If you are using session_start() Place your php script before any HTML code.
You cannot use or have an output before `session_start()` not even an `echo`.
e.g.

```
<?php
session_start();#creates a session or resumes the current 
include(lib/inc.php);
?>    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Title</title>
   <head>
   <body>
     <p>text</p>
   <body>
</html>
```

An other solution if you must have an output is to use `ob_start` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php